# Ecto Model - subquery in select

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I need to make this SQL query with Ecto:

```
SELECT users.*, (select count(0) from money_transactions where from_id = users.id AND created_at > '2016-1-25 0:00:00.000000') as money_transactions_today_db FROM "users" WHERE "users"."client_token" = '123'
```

I try to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
query = from users in Like4uElixir.User,
        where: users.client_token in ^tokens,
        select: {users, (from money_transactions in Like4uElixir.MoneyTransaction,
                            where: money_transactions.from_id == users.id,
                            select: count(0))}
```

Does Ecto support subqueries? If not, how can I execute the query?

Answer (score 14):

You can use query fragments:

```
query = from users in Like4uElixir.User,
        where: users.client_token in ^tokens,
        select: {users, (fragment("(SELECT COUNT(0) FROM money_transactions
                                    WHERE money_transactions.from_id == ?)", users.id))}
```

Although in this case the query can also be written using regular joins and group_by. Current support for subqueries in Ecto is limited.

Comment: Unfortunally it doesn't work: 
(Postgrex.Error) ERROR (syntax_error): syntax error at or near "SELECT".
I finished making the query with JOIN & GROUP BY as you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, you need parens around SELECT ... in the fragment. I have updated my answer.